# Showing that $d$ is a metric

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, random-variables

> For any two random variables $X$ and $Y$, denote by $d(X,Y)$ the infimum of such numbers $\epsilon >0$ that $P(|X-Y|>\epsilon)<\epsilon$.Show that $d$ is a metric on the set of classes of equivalent rv's (random variables $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent if $X=Y$ with probability 1).

I was able to show the positivity and transitivity of $d$ since it's quite obvious. But how should I show that $d(X,Z)\le d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)$? Can I assume $P(|X-Y|)=P(|X-Z|)=P(|Y-Z|)$ since $X,Y,Z$ are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I assume $P(|X-Y|)=P(|X-Z|)=P(|Y-Z|)$ since $X,Y,Z$ are equivalent?

This would not prove the triangle inequality, since $X, Y$, and $Z$ may not all be equivalent.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Choose positive numbers $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ such that $\epsilon_1 < d(X,Y) + \epsilon/2$ and $\epsilon_2 < d(Y,Z) + \epsilon/2$. If $P(\lvert X - Y\rvert > \epsilon_1) < \epsilon_1$ and $P(\lvert Y - Z\rvert > \epsilon_2) < \epsilon_2$, then $$P(\lvert X - Z\rvert > \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2) \le P(\lvert X - Y\rvert > \epsilon_1) + P(\lvert Y - Z\rvert > \epsilon_2) < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$$
Therefore

$$d(X,Z) \le \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 < d(X,Y) + d(Y,Z) + \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the triangle inequality holds.